¿Como acomodar archivos en carpetas de acuerdo a un identificador del archivo?
solicito su ayuda ya que estoy haciendo un script para poder acomodar archivos que tengo en mis descargas, pero me gustaria acomodarlos de acuerdo al identificador que tiene cada archivo. Mis archivos son .inc y .pc de extensión, pero por ejemplo pueden existir los archivos:

erlAA01.inc y erlAA01.pc

erlAA150.inc y erlAA150.pc


Pero me gustaría guardarlos como en la siguiente estructura:

nombre_Carpeta: erlAA001 y el contenido sea los archivos erlAA01.inc y erlAA01.pc
nombre_Carpeta: erlAA150 y el contenido sea los archivos erlAA150.inc y erlAA150.pc

Necesito que se guarden de manera dinámica, ya que actualmente mi codigo guarda todo en una sola carpeta, además igual lo guarda en carpetas separadas cada archivo, entonces lo que necesito es que el script reconozca el identificador y guarde todos los archivos .pc y .inc que se llamen igual en una sola carpeta, pero si el identificador cambia, que se cree otra carpeta y los guarde ahi.
import os
import shutil

directorio_origen = 'C:/Users/usuario/Downloads'
directorio_destino = input('Elige la dirección donde quieres introducir tus archivos:\n')



# Comprobar si el directorio de destino existe, si no, crearlo
if not os.path.exists(directorio_destino):
   os.makedirs(directorio_destino)

# Obtener la lista de archivos en el directorio de origen
archivos = os.listdir(directorio_origen)

# Buscar un archivo con la extensión .inc o .pc para usar su nombre como nombre de carpeta
nombre_carpeta = None
for archivo in archivos:
   if archivo.endswith('.inc') or archivo.endswith('.pc'):
       nombre_carpeta = os.path.splitext(archivo)[0]
       break

if nombre_carpeta is None:
   print("No se encontraron archivos con las extensiones .inc o .pc en el directorio de 
   origen.")
   exit()

# Crear la ruta completa del directorio de destino
ruta_carpeta_destino = os.path.join(directorio_destino, nombre_carpeta)

# Comprobar si la carpeta de destino ya existe, si no, crearla

if not os.path.exists(ruta_carpeta_destino):
   os.makedirs(ruta_carpeta_destino)

# Iterar sobre cada archivo
for archivo in archivos:
# Obtener la extensión del archivo
   nombre, extension = os.path.splitext(archivo)
# Verificar si la extensión es .inc o .pc
   if extension in ['.inc', '.pc'] :
       ruta_origen = os.path.join(directorio_origen, archivo)
       ruta_destino = os.path.join(ruta_carpeta_destino, archivo)
       shutil.copy2(ruta_origen, ruta_destino)
       print(f"Archivo {archivo} copiado correctamente a {ruta_destino}")

Espero me puedan apoyar. Muchas gracias

Básicamente tu código tiene todos los ingredientes para hacer lo que deseas. El problema es que rompes el primer ciclo for en el que obtienes el nombre de la carpeta de destino en cuanto encuentras el primer archivo a copiar y usas esta carpeta para copiar todos los archivos que encuentras.
Debes generar la ruta de la carpeta de destino para cada archivo que se encuentre, comprobar si ya existe esa carpeta, crearla si no existe y copiar el archivo.
Es decir, algo como:
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


EXTENSIONES = {'.inc', '.pc'}
directorio_origen = 'C:/Users/usuario/Downloads'
directorio_destino = input('Elige la dirección donde quieres introducir tus archivos:\n')

ruta_dir_origen = Path(directorio_origen)
ruta_dir_destino = Path(directorio_destino)

if not ruta_dir_destino.exists():
    ruta_dir_destino.mkdir()

ruta_destino = None
for ruta_origen in ruta_dir_origen.iterdir():
    if ruta_origen.is_file() and ruta_origen.suffix in EXTENSIONES:
        ruta_destino = ruta_dir_destino.joinpath(ruta_origen.stem)

        if not ruta_destino.exists():
            ruta_destino.mkdir()

        shutil.copy2(ruta_origen, ruta_destino)
        print(f"Archivo {ruta_origen} copiado correctamente a {ruta_destino}")

if ruta_destino is None:
    print("No se encontraron archivos con las extensiones .inc o .pc en el directorio de origen.")
        

    

Uso pathlib en vez de os porque me parece algo más amena, pero de cualquier forma la idea es la misma.
Ten en cuenta que si la ruta ingresada como destino no es válida o por alguna razón no se pueden crear los directorios (por falta de permisos por ejemplo) el script terminará con una excepción (FileNotFoundError, PermissionError, ...) que tal vez te interese manejar.

Edición
De acuerdo al comentario del OP:

Mis identificadores pueden ser variables por ejemplo tengo un archivo
llamado: ERL_XA03-USZASB1_48_2.pc, pero a su vez tengo un
ERL_mar_XA03-fzg.inc. Entonces ¿cómo seria en ese caso? Además de que
por ejemplo busco que el nombre de la carpeta siempre lleve el nombre
del .pc.

En este caso deberemos primero obtener el identificador gracias al patrón que sigue, en este caso una regex como:
_([^_-]+)-.+\.(pc|inc)$

(Ver Online), nos debería valer.
Segundo, debemos asignar el nombre a la carpeta de destino de acuerdo al nombre de los .pc, esto nos obliga o bien a iterar sobre el directorio dos veces (una para listar los .pc y crear los directorios de destino y otro para copiar los archivos) o usar algún contenedor intermedio.
Por ejemplo:
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import re


ID_REGEX_DIRS = re.compile(r"_([^_-]+)-")
ID_REGEX_FILES = re.compile(r"_([^_-]+)-.+\.(pc|inc)$")

directorio_origen = 'C:/Users/usuario/Downloads'
directorio_destino = input('Elige la dirección donde quieres introducir tus archivos:\n')

ruta_dir_origen = Path(directorio_origen)
ruta_dir_destino = Path(directorio_destino)

if not ruta_dir_destino.exists():
    ruta_dir_destino.mkdir()

archivos_a_copiar = {}
# En el caso que existan directorios en el destino, prepopular el diccionario con ellos
for ruta in ruta_dir_destino.iterdir():
    if ruta.is_dir() and (match_ := ID_REGEX_DIRS.search(ruta.name)) is not None:
        archivos_a_copiar[match_.group(1)] = {"ruta_destino": ruta, "rutas_a_copiar": []}

for ruta_origen in ruta_dir_origen.iterdir():
    if ruta_origen.is_file() and (match_ := ID_REGEX_FILES.search(ruta_origen.name)) is not None:
        identificador = match_.group(1)
        if (destino := archivos_a_copiar.get(identificador)) is None:
            destino = {
                "ruta_destino": ruta_dir_destino.joinpath(ruta_origen.stem) if ruta_origen.suffix == ".pc" else None,
                "rutas_a_copiar": [ruta_origen]
            }
            archivos_a_copiar[identificador] = destino
        else:
            destino["rutas_a_copiar"].append(ruta_origen)

for destino in archivos_a_copiar.values():
    ruta_destino, rutas_a_copiar = destino.values()
    if ruta_destino is not None:
        if not ruta_destino.exists():
            ruta_destino.mkdir()
        for ruta_origen in rutas_a_copiar:
            shutil.copy2(ruta_origen, ruta_destino)
            print(f"Archivo {ruta_origen} copiado correctamente a {ruta_destino}")

En este caso se usa un diccionario para asociar los identificadores con el directorio de destino correspondiente y los archivos a copiar en el.
Dos apuntes:

Si hay archivos .inc cuyo identificador no tiene ya una carpeta de destino existente previamente y tampoco hay un .pc con ese mismo identificador en la carpeta de origen, no serán copiados.

Si ya hay una carpeta existente para un identificador dado, de encontrarse un .pc con ese identificador, se copiara en ella pero el nombre de la carpeta se mantendrá. Igualmente, si existen varios .pc con el mismo identificador, el nombre de la carpeta de destino será el del primero encontrado y todos se copiarán en ella.



Hola @FJSevilla agradezco tu ayuda, me ha ayudado mucho, pero por ejemplo si a veces el archivo se llama ERLCSAA003.inc pero tengo un ERLAA003.pc como hago para guardar esos archivos por el identificador AA003 por ejemplo que es el que nunca se modifica. Espero tu respuesta gracias

@EmanuelRangel si tus archivos siempre tienen esos últimos 5 caracteres en su nombre como identificador (no hay archivos en los que la longitud o posición del identificador sea distinta como algoA003.inc, o algoAA02.inc, o algoAAA0003.inc, o algoAA003otracosa.inc, etc) basta con hacer un indexado negativo del stem para obtener esos últimos 5 caracteres:          ruta_destino = ruta_dir_destino.joinpath(ruta_origen.stem[-5:]) . El nombre de las carpetas en este caso será el identificador (AA003, AB001, DE124, etc)

Si el identificador es variable, entonces deberás obtenerlo de forma apropiada, las regex pueden serte de ayuda. De cualquier forma el algoritmo sería el mismo, simplemente habría que extraer la subcadena correcta del identificador de ruta_origen.stem para generar la ruta de la carpeta de destino correspondiente.

si por ejemplo mis identificadores pueden ser variables por ejemplo tengo un archivo llamado:
ERL_XA03-USZASB1_48_2.pc. Pero a su vez tengo un ERL_mar_XA03-fzg.inc
Entonces como seria en ese caso?
Ademas de que por ejemplo busco que el nombre de la carpeta siempre lleve el nombre del .pc. Espero me puedas ayudar muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

Lo de que la carpeta tenga el nombre del .pc es sencillo (siempre que sea un solo archivo .pc por carpeta/identificador). Lo del identificador variable, la clave está en que tienen que tener un patrón en común ¿Cual es? Es decir, para que lo que quieres sea siquiera posible debe haber alguna forma de detectar el identificador siempre, en tu ejemplo parece que el id está siempre antecedido por un _ y al final hay un - (loquesea_IDENTIFICADOR-loquesea), si es así y se asegura que no hay más - en los nombres aparte de ese, sería bastante simple con una regex sacarlos.

Podrias ayudarme con ese tema de las regex por favor @FJSevilla ya que desconozco el tema de las regex modifique la siguiente linea de esta forma, pero no funciono
ruta_destino = re.search(ruta_dir_destino.joinpath("^_.*-$",ruta_origen.stem))
Te lo agradeceria muchisimo

@EmanuelRangel mira la edición de mi respuesta a ver si te ayuda. La expresión regular está basada en el ejemplo que das en tu antepenúltimo comentario, no se si los dos ejemplos representan todas las variaciones posibles o no.

Hola @FJSevilla si claro que me ayudo, muchas gracias agradezco tu tiempo y dedicacion a respondes mis preguntas, pero solo tengo una última duda que, si en el dado caso bueno por ejemplo tenemos el nombre de los archivos con el XA03, pero si hubiera un XA04 como lo podria identificar en ese caso? digamos todos los archivos igual solo que unos son XA03 y XA04. Espero puedas ayudarme muchas gracias

con ese código y REGEX XA03 y XA04 serian considerados distintos e irían cada uno a una carpeta distinta ¿Te refieres a que todos los archivos con "XANN" terminen en la misma carpeta independientemente del número?

Bueno mas que nada independientemente de las letras o de los numero cada archivo debe estar en la carpeta que le corresponde los XA03 en una sola carpeta los XA04 en otra carpeta y puede darse el caso de que existan los BA01 o BA02, pero cada uno debe estar en su carpeta correspondiente de acuerdo a letra y numeros. Espero que me hayas entendido, de cualquier forma responderé la duda que tengas. por favor y gracias

Una pequeña actualizacion @FJSevilla los nombres tienen doble "__" entonces por ejemplo seria ERL__XA03-USZASB1_48_2.pc. Una disculpa por omitir ese detalle

Si cada uno va a su carpeta es lo que hace (si no he metido la pata...) el código de mi última actualización, aunque hay que actualizar la REGEX por lo del doble guion bajo. ¿Los .inc serían ERL_mar__XA03-fzg.inc o ERL__mar_XA03-fzg.inc?, porque si es el segundo complica las cosas algo más.

Mira te pondre un ejemplo real de nombres de archivos que uso.
De los .pc seria:
MMA-SD__XA03-ERLCFG_0_0-D_120-50-1-1E46_1.pc
De los .inc seria:
MMA-SD__Mat__XA03-fzg.inc
Espero quede más claro, y una disculpara por confundirte tanto

Si te fijas para ambos archivos que pones la expresión identifica correctamente el identificador (XA03): https://regex101.com/r/7fKozW/1 (el ID es el grupo 1, marcado en verde). No deberías tener problemas a no ser que existan archivos con patrón no representado por esos ejemplos.

No, pues de hecho así son los archivos que manejo.
Entonces bueno, no sé si haya algún problema por lo del doble guion bajo __
Y bueno corrí una prueba, pero todos los archivos me los sigue poniendo en una sola carpeta

Creo que ya haye el problema.
Como maneja mucha cantidad de archivos, pero no me di cuenta de que algunos archivos se llaman asi
443_MMA-SD__Mat__XA03-fzg.inc
443_MMA-SD__XA03-ERLCFG_0_0-D_120-50-1-1E46_1.pc
Pero digamos toma estos de ejemplo ya que la mayoria son de esta forma

Si solo es eso, debería bastar con cambiar la expresiones a __([^_-]+)- y __([^_-]+)-.+\.(pc|inc)$: https://regex101.com/r/39DaKT/1

Hola @FJSevilla ya hice los cambios, pero no copia los archivos, esta raro porque si cambio el nombre de los archivos a un solo guion bajo los cambia, pero si le pongo los dos guiones bajos no hace nada. Espero me puedas apoyar gracias
